# Twice differentiable function with equal endpoints

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus

Let $f: [0, 2\pi]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a twice differentiable function satisfying
$$\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)dx = 0, \quad f(0) = f(2\pi)$$
I want to show that
$$\int_0^{2\pi}[f(x)]^2dx \leq \int_0^{2\pi}[f'(x)]^2dx$$

---

I've tried breaking this down into three cases. The case $f(0) = 0 = f(2\pi)$, or $f(0)=f(2\pi) > 0$, or $f(0) = f(2\pi) < 0$, and then partitioning the domain from there, but this effort did not get anywhere.

Then I tried a proof by contradiction, and I think I have it right but I'm not sure.
So, suppose that $\int_0^{2\pi} [f(x)]^2 dx > \int_0^{2\pi}[f'(x)]^2dx$, then
\begin{equation} I = \int_0^{2\pi}[f(x)]^2dx - \int_0^{2\pi}[f'(x)]^2 dx > 0 \qquad (1)\end{equation}
Applying integration by parts on the left integral of $I$, choosing $u = f(x)$, $dv = f(x)dx$, then $du = f'(x)dx$ and $v = \int_0^{2\pi}f(x)dx = 0$. Hence,
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{2\pi}[f(x)]^2dx &= [f(2\pi)-f(0)]\int_0^{2\pi}0dx - \int0\cdot f'(x)dx \\
&= 0 
\end{align*}
Applying integration by parts on the right integral in (1) gives the same result, hence $I = 0$, and $I > 0$ is a contradiction. Therefore, $$\int_0^{2\pi}[f(x)]^2dx \leq \int_0^{2\pi}[f'(x)]^2dx$$

Comment: Note that your first result applying integration parts basically got that $\int_0^{2\pi}[f(x)]^2dx=0$. However, since $[f(x)]^2 \ge 0$, then for any continuous, real function $f(x)$, this means that $f(x)=0\;\forall\;0\le x\le2\pi$.

Comment: There is a mistake in the integration by parts: $v$ must be some primitive $F$ of $f$ (for instance $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$), not a real number.

Comment: This inequality has a name, it's called Writinger's inequality. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger%27s_inequality_for_functions